# How to transmit parameters in the jqgrid

Tags: jquery, url, jqgrid

```
jQuery(function(){ 
var year        =   jQuery("#historyQuery").val();
var projectCode =   jQuery("#projectCode").val();

  jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    hidegrid:false,
    height:300,
    pgbuttons:false,
    pginput:false,
    url:'index.php?option=com_projectdetails&view=details&task=ajaxdetails.getProjectDetails&format=xml',
    // editurl:'index.php?option=com_cwmaintain&view=incharge&task=ajaxincharge.editcwmaintain&format=xml',
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'post',
    colNames:['日期','凭证号','摘要','收入/拨出','支出/拨出','借还款'],
    colModel :[ 
      {name:'N3', index:'N3', width:110,sortable:false,editable:false}, 
      {name:'N4', index:'N4', width:110,sortable:false,editable:true,editrules:{required:true}},
      {name:'N5', index:'N5', width:110,sortable:false,editable:true,editrules:{required:true}},
      {name:'N7', index:'N7', width:110,sortable:false,editable:true,editrules:{required:true}},
      {name:'N6', index:'N6', width:110,sortable:false,editable:true,editrules:{required:true}},
      {name:'N6', index:'N6', width:110,sortable:false,editable:true,editrules:{required:true}},
    ],
    rowNum:20,
    reccount:10,
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    pager: '#pager',
    caption: '部门负责人'                // jqgrid标题
  }); 
jQuery("#list").navGrid('#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:true,refresh:true}); 
});
```

I want to transmit the two paramaters named **year** and **projectCode** to the function of `getProjectDetails($year,$projectCode)`, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Statically you can use `postData` to add parameters to the request like

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({   
...
postData:{year:year,projectCode:projectCode },
```

....
Dynamically you can use `setGridParam` method  and again use the postData as parameter.
Please refer to the [documentation page](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods#grid_related_methods)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you should add additional `postData` option to jqGrid where you define properties of `postData` as functions:

```
postData: {
    year: function () { return $("#historyQuery").val(); },
    projectCode: function () { return $("#projectCode").val(); }
}
```

In the case the *current* values from `"#historyQuery"` and `$("#projectCode")` will be get on every new request to the server. It's important to understand that `year` and `projectCode` will be *not appended* to the URL because you use `mtype: 'post'` option. The parameters will be send in the body of the request in the same way like parameters `page`, `rows`, `sidx`, `sord` and `_search`.

See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935) for more details.